# How to force cast Struct from super type into new type?

Tags: ios, swift

From the code below, I created instances of struct type.

The problem is I want to create array which contain any struct with `supernoob` protocol .

But I have no idea how to cast it from ancestor type (`supernoob`) to `noob` type, I cant access to ( `var pro` ) without casting.

I can cast it very easy when working with class but I have no idea for struct .

```
import UIKit

protocol supernoob{
  func superdoNoob()
  var supernub:String { get set }
}

struct noob: supernoob{
  var supernub: String
  func superdoNoob() {

  }
  var pro:String
}

struct spaceShip{
  var mynoob : supernoob
}

let flyAlien = spaceShip(mynoob: noob(supernub: "choopa", pro: "PO"))
let ufo = spaceShip(mynoob: noob(supernub: "choopa", pro: "PO"))

let array = [flyAlien,ufo]


ufo.mynoob as? noob
```

Comment: Where is the question

Comment: `let noob = ufo.mynoob as? noob`,  `let pro = noob?.pro`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if a cast is possible by doing `if let...`

```
for item in array {
    if let noob = item.mynoob as? noob {
        print(noob.pro)
    }
}
```